# Adding to every specific word in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add a comment and change the font color to red for every instance of a specific word found in the text. Using `Selection.Find` I can only change the font color to red - is there is a way to also add a comment to every found word?

```
Sub WordSearcher(word)
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorGreen
  With Selection.Find
        .Text = word
        '.Replacement.Text = word
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I wrote the below code, which does both things, but it's not very effective, since it takes several minutes to go through whole document - is there a way to do this in a more reasonable time?

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrWords)
            If Trim(UCase(ActiveDocument.Words(i))) = UCase(arrWords(j)) Then
                ActiveDocument.Words(i).Font.Color = vbRed
                ActiveDocument.Comments.Add ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Words(i).Start, ActiveDocument.Words(i).End), arrComments(j)
            End If
        Next j
Next
```

Comment: Confused - are you using the first block of code or why is it there? How many words are in your document and how many in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It involves interrupting the Find at each "found" in order to add the comment. In order to do this effectively, it's better to work with a `Range` object, not with `Selection`.

The `Find.Execute` method returns a boolean: true when the Find is successful. You can use this to test whether a comment should be inserted and also to know when the code should stop.

Note it's also important to use `Find.Wrap = wdFindStop` to avoid the code looping "infinitely".

```
Sub FindRedAndComment()
    Dim rngFind As word.Range
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim sFindText As String
    Dim sCommentText As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rngFind = doc.content
    sFindText = "test"
    sCommentText = "comment"
    With rngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        .Text = sFindText
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
  End With
  Do Until Not bFound
      If bFound Then
        doc.Comments.Add rngFind, sCommentText
        rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rngFind.End = doc.content.End
        bFound = rngFind.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
      End If
  Loop
End Sub
```